# Approval email response comments are being cut short

Tags: email, approval-process

Whenever I reply to an approval process email with comments in the second line, the comments are getting cut off around 75 characters. They are consistently being cut off at the end of a full word, which leads me to believe that my email is being sent with line breaks added by the server (I use google apps for business).

Has anyone encountered this before? Other than going to the approval detail page to leave comments, is there a known workaround to be able to send approval comments in the email?

Comment: What format are your replies being sent in? Are they being sent as HTML or as text? If the latter, are you able to open the text documents to search for line breaks?

Comment: good luck with this as the SFDC approve-by-email process hasn't seen much development in the last few years